# Filter a nested list in an AngularJS Template and get the count of the filtered data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to filter a nested list with AngularJS and count the number if filtered nested items returned?

The goal is to filter each item by `read:true`.

Here is the data:

```
guest = [
  {"id":148,"guest":2,"user":1,"read":true},
  {"id":147,"guest":2,"user":1,"read":false},
  {"id":58,"guest":2,"user":1,"read":false}
]
```

This array is called `guest` and each item in the array is a `message`.

Would the template filter syntax go something like this?

```
{{ (for m in guest.messages | filter: m.read: true).length }}
```

The key here is that this *does not use ng-repeat*.  There are a lot of answers on how to do this with *ng-repeat*, but not with filtering a nested list in a single statement.

Is this possible in the `template`, or maybe the only way to do this is in the `controller`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple custom filter would likely be best from a code readability standpoint in the view

```
app.filter('numRead', function(){
   return function(guestArr){
     return guestArr.filter(function(guest){
       return guest.read;
     }).length
   }      
});
```

Usage:

```
Read count = {{guest| numRead}}
```

### [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/qbsbeSia2EVyC87xopdU?p=preview)

Comment: `guest.messages` is the array that needs to be filtered, so I updated that in the answer.  Other than that, thank you so much.  This is an awesome! answer, and exactly what I was trying to do.  Thank you!

Comment: ok I was just matching the data shown and in the demo, generally better to make them all match otherwise question and answer are different and can confuse future readers

Comment: @chrlietfl I removed my edit.  You are correct.  All should match, and the `guest.messages` part was from my source code, so is not important.  Thank you again.